# Two ways creating Java System.currentTimeMillis() in C# produce different output

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need an equivalent of Java System.currentTimeMillis in C#. Based on definition of System.currentTimeMillis:

> the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and
>   midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC

I come up with 2 ways:

Way 1: Using `DateTime.UtcNow` & `DateTimeKind.Utc`

```
(long)(DateTime.UtcNow 
    - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds
```

Way 2: Using `DateTime.Now` & `DateTimeKind.Local`

```
(long)(DateTime.Now 
    - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local)).TotalMilliseconds
```

Results:

WAY 1: 15331**4**8186919  --> This is correct answer.

WAY 2: 15331**3**0186929

Anyone knows why WAY 2 produce wrong result?

Comment: Because it is based on UTC?

Comment: Your local UTC offset is +1 currently right?

Comment: WAY 1: Both DateTime are based on UTC. WAY 2: Both DateTime are based on Local so I think the different will be the same?

Comment: What about DST which could be a factor in #2 depending on where/when `DateTime.Now` was called but won't be in 1.

Comment: @Progressive: My local UTC offset is -05:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be explained by DST. This could be a factor in #2 depending on when and also on what machine's locale `DateTime.Now` was called.